# How to map structured data to schemaRDD with scala or python?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I have a structured data that want to map to schemaRDD. The data looks like this:

```
{recordType:NEW,data:{keycol:val1,col2:val2,col3:val3,col4:val4}
{recordType:update,data:{keycol:val1,col2:val5,col3:val6,col4:val7}
```

and I like to be able to run sql after mapping it to schemaRDD like this:

```
select keycol, col1, col2 from tableT1 where col3 = val3
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Me waana see some code. What have you treid ? We can help solving problems in your code. But we won't give you the full code.

Comment: Why not? I think a general question -> general answer is a great format. It will help many programmers that face the same problem in the future. I know _I_ will face this problem in a few weeks, so I'm looking forward to the answer :).

Comment: My scala/python knowledge is very limited so I'm looking for a right approach for such a problem. Any help is appreciated.